# How to access objects and variables while debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm debugging an Eclipse project in which I have an object (specifically a **ResourceDelta** object), In the **Variables** view I can see a lot of useful information that I need but I'm not sure how to access those values, i.e. this is how my **Variables** view looks like while I'm debugging:

[image]

I need to get the **newInfo** and **oldInfo** values, but if I use the content assistant in the **test1** object only this methods are available:

[image]

How can I get those values?

Comment: What about expanding the nodes?

Comment: Yes, but I need to get that values programmatically, in other words, I need to assign those values to another variables, sorry if I'm not explaining myself well, English is not my first language

Comment: Are you sure those variables are not accessible? Are they private?

Comment: They are not private, I was expecting to access those values something like this `test1.oldInfo` and `test1.newInfo` but I guess it's not that easy :)

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the tree for `newinfo` or `oldinfo` in the variables window - clicking the > just before that variable will show the details of that object , along with their values.

Comment: What I need to do is to get that values programmatically, in other words, I need to assign those values to another variables, I was expecting to access those objects like this `test1.oldInfo` and `test1.newInfo` but `oldInfo` and `newInfo` are not listed in the content assistant, but in the `Variables` view I can see that they are under `test1` object.

Comment: This depends upon the access modifiers on the `newinfo` and `oldinfo` members defined inside the `ResourceDelta` class. I am suspecting these are declared as `protected`. The debugger in eclipse is able to show even private members so dont be confused into thinking that this alone should allow you to access these fields programmatically.